# Match only uppercase word

Tags: cpu-word, uppercase

I have a text string:
`"Cena celkem bez DPH: 598.556,00 CZK  Celkem CZK 724.252,76"`
and I would like to match only `CZK`.

I wanted to use `(?i)(?:CELKEM)\s+([A-Z]{2,3})` but it matches also the word `"bez"` not only `"CZK"` as I wanted.

I am using python and regular expressions.
Thank you very much

Comment: The string is always the same format? If yes, what format? What programming language (solution could differ)?

Comment: the programming language is Python

Comment: we are using regular expressions to match certain values

Comment: With `(?i)` you are applying the `i` modifier for case-insensititive matching to the rest of your pattern.